# Where can i find documentation for python built-in modules?

Tags: python, built-in

Python has some built-in modules e.g _random, _ast, _collections, _md5, _functools and more.

In all of python implementations standard libraries are built using this built-in modules.
But I can't find any documentation for this modules. Is there any documentation?

full list of this modules:

```
import sys
sys.builtin_module_names
```

Comment: I like using [`devdocs`](https://devdocs.io/python~3.6/) for quick searching through the python docs.

Comment: The underscore-prefixed modules are for the implementation of the non-underscore modules. You shouldn’t need them and they aren’t documented as part of the standard library.

Comment: @DeliriousLettuce. I'm not searching for stdlib docs.

Comment: @Ryan No! I'm reviewed source codes (Cpython and stdlib). e.g `_random` is not `random`.

Comment: @MinaaN: Correct, `_random` is not `random`. I never said it was, though. `_random` is used to implement `random`. It’s not documented outside its source because nobody else is supposed to use it.

Comment: @MinaaN https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3070b71e5eedf62e49b8e7dedab75742a5f67ece/Modules/_randommodule.c

Comment: @Ryan Yes, `_X` is used to implement `X`. 

*It’s not documented outside its source because nobody else is supposed to use it.* Are you sure?

Comment: @MinaaN: Yes, I’m sure.

Comment: @Ryan So Bad! And if someone wants to use this modules or wants to contributing to stdlib? Reviewing source code completely + Trial and error?

Comment: @MinaaN: Why would someone want to use the modules? The intent is for their functionality to be exposed by other modules that are public. Contributing to them works the same as changing any other source that’s not part of a public API.

Comment: @Ryan Any reason, because someone want!

Comment: @MinaaN A part of the standard python naming convention is that __any__ name preceded with underscore is a private implementation detail which it is not _guaranteed_ will remain consistent or even present so should generally not be used.

Answer (score 0):

<s>If you are using Python 3.x, here:
https://docs.python.org/3/py-modindex.html</s>

If you are using Python 2.7, here:
https://docs.python.org/2.7/py-modindex.html

It is called the Python Module Index. You can click on a specific module to look at its documentation.

I was wrong. These modules are not built-in. These links are perfectly fine if you want the modules in the standard library, but that is not what OP was asking for.

Comment: I'm not talking about python stdlib. Your references are stdlib docs. "built-in modules" are not "stdlib".

Comment: @MinaaN. Right. I have edited my answer to reflect that. Thanks for the correction.